# A query to check the max id and update another field with max id and year

Tags: php, mysql

I have a scenario in which when i update a record the query should update the max(id_inc) + 1 from the table 'Process'. Next it needs to update another field inv_id_inc in the same table 'Process' with a simple concat function (SELECT CONCAT(max(inv_id) , '/', 16). That is it should update as 1/16, then 2/16, then 3/16 etc. 16 is the current year short form. I am not sure if i can achieve this in one query. At present i tried with 2 queries. First query it updates max(id_inc) + 1 and second query it concatenate CONCAT(max(inv_id) , '/', 16. Iam not sure if iam doing correct.

```
================================
tender_id | id_inc | inv_id_inc
================================
  200     |   1    |   1/16
  300     |   2    |   2/16
```

My First Query is below:.

```
update process
set  inv_id=
SELECT MAX( inv_id ) + 1 FROM process where tender_id=200;
```

My second query is below:

```
update process t
join (SELECT CONCAT(max(inv_id) , '/', 16) as inv_id_inc
    from process ) t1
set t.inv_id_inc=t1.inv_id_inc WHERE tender_id='200'";
```

Its not updating. Can anyone suggest me a solution please.?

Now its working. I changed 2 queries. The updated queries are below:

FIRST QUERY:

```
UPDATE process set inv_id = ((SELECT inv_id FROM (SELECT MAX(inv_id) AS inv_id FROM process) 
AS inv_id_new) + 1) WHERE tender_id='200'
```

SECOND QUERY:

```
update process t
join (SELECT CONCAT(max(inv_id), '/', 16) as inv_id_inc
    from process ) t1
set t.inv_id_inc=t1.inv_id_inc WHERE tender_id='200'
```

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Are you using `PHP` anywhere?

Comment: its a php application. Iam just trying with a query.

Comment: I guess my question is not clear. :)

Comment: Can anyone help me on this?

Comment: perhaps you should describe what you are trying to achieve! I have a feeling you are using bad technique or incorrect terminology. **when i update a record** update or insert? and this all sounds table trigger operation to me!

Comment: Thank you. I tried to explain. Not getting to explain perfectly. Anyways thanx. I am trying myself.

Comment: Your explanation should involve the scenario you are looking for, not just the actions you are trying to perform. Your story now feels like you are trying to accomplish something that doesn't need to be handled the way you do.

Comment: @RST  Thank you so much for the info. Next time i will try to try and explain the scenario as well.